# How to manage schema in a different database from within a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have a simple Rails app which populates into a certain database and there are few migration scripts. I would like to create a different set of model classes and actually migrate the schema pertaining to those files into a different database. How should we do that? Will I be able to do this from the same rails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, change the `database name` in database.yml , then follow the usual steps,
`bundle exec rake db:setup` should do the work.

Or you could create a seperate `database_2.yml` and then make a database.rake file and follow the steps [here](http://nikalyuk.in/blog/2013/06/21/connecting-rails-project-with-multiple-databases/)